# Looking for a VSCode Extension which creates a selectors-map (HTML)

Tags: html-editor, visual-studio-code

I'am currently searching for a VSCode extension which creates a list/tree of all selectors in a HTML document. I found some extensions like "Codemap", but all of those aren't working with HTML. The integrated vsc DOM tree is too detailed and doesn't really helps.. I need a simple (linked-)list of all IDs (maybe classes, too).

May someone has an idea :)